# Is Blender compatible with Windows 10?

Tags: windows

Will Blender still work on Windows 10, and if so, will the full screen functionality still work? Are there any issues with Blender and Windows 10 I should be aware of before upgrading?

Comment: I don't see a reason why Blender wouldn't work on Windows 10. You can use old versions of Blender that where designed for older versions of Windows just fine on newer versions of Windows.

Comment: I feel like you have a fundamental misconception of how Blender interacts with Windows...

Comment: I think something important to grasp, is that if Windows 10 completely changed the program API from what if used to be, a lot of software companies would probably get a bit angry, and it would be bad for business.

Comment: I had issue with Windows 10 and Blender 2.76. Apparently, I have a Microsoft Mouse and when Windows 10 was installed the default behavior of  mouse wheel button became to invoke so-called "Instant Viewer". Because of that I could not pan with pressing mouse wheel in Blender. Changed it to "Middle click" in Windows settings and not it works fine.

Answer (score 8):

I am running Blender 2.75 on Windows 10 now, the 10240 RTM release, and it is working without any issues compared to my previous run on Windows 8.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

As far as we know right now, no, there won't be any issues.

Windows probably couldn't afford a major change in their programming API that effect Blender.

It would probably make a few large software companies a bit angry.

As far as the fullscreen functionality, this is something that shouldn't really be effected much by the platform. If it wasn't working on a specific platform (that Blender can run on), it would be a major bug. Lot's of people (including myself) use this all the time to help focus on our work a bit more, and loosing the functionality would probably make half the community extremely angry.

*Just a disclaimer, I haven't tried Windows 10, so I can't say for sure that Blender won't work on it, but I am extremely confident that it will.*

Answer (score 2):

I've just installed windows 10 and blender crashes instantly at start up. To make it run I've discovered that one must start the application directly from the directory and specify the graphic acceleration available by clicking the right button of the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I have W10 Pro (build 10240)  Blender 2.76 (2015-10-11)

Running multiple instance of Blender 24 hours a day for 1 month. Blender hasn't crashed

Full screen functionality.. not sure what that is. If it is where you CTRL right arrow to change the screen windows, yes can see the 3D view full screen and also drag new windows into it to see multiple views)

(Can pan with middle wheel click.)