# Texture paint - lags

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting

I'm using blender v2.76 in cycles render.
I'm trying to texture paint on my model(21k verticels). But blender lags, on small brush, big bush, etc.

My texture is 2048x2048 in resolution. I have **nVidia 960M,8 GB RAM, i7 4720HQ processor** so that should not be a problem. I try to disable use nodes. I have no active modifiers on model.

I tried to active region **overlap option** in system preferences, and window draw method to **Triple Buffering**.

Image texture is generated from blender and is 16 bit(not 32). **Occlude, Cull, Normal** options disabled or enabled. Still no change and disabled smooth option for brush.

I thought my last pc was no so good, so I buy new one for blender and get same issues. (That drives me mad) .

Can somebody help me ? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to find out which factor (texture size or mesh density) affects most your issue?

Comment: @m.ardito Both the same way but mesh density maybe a little bit more I think. If i zoom to model and paint a small area, it lags for 2 seconds. if i zoom out with same brush and paint edge of the model. it is better but if I outzoom a lot and paint half of the model or full model. it lags and i had to restart blender.

Comment: What are the active modifiers on the model? Have you tried to paint not on model directly in 3D View, rather than on texture in UV/Image Editor? Have you experienced such problems with other files? Probably you should import this model into another .blend? Does your OS respond fast in other programs? And also: maybe there is something to change with your OS, not with Blender.

Comment: As I said, there are no modifiers on object. I tried it on different pc with same result. I also try to just start up cube and get same lags. I'm painting on 3D model not to UV/Image Editor. Now I download older version and try if the problem persist. @MrZak

Comment: From your question: "..I have active modifiers on model... " From your comment: "As I said, there are no modifiers on object...." Please edit either one of them so they to fit each other. As to lags - I haven't ever had and still don't have such problems on computer with much less powerful configuration, so it seems to me this is not Blender related problem. But you're right, check everything, including downgrading to older version.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry for missdirect. Are you using windows 10 ? Older version does not help to me :/. @MrZak

Comment: I'm using Win7 32 bit. Does your PC work properly while in other programs? If yes, then taking into account your PC system configs and that Blender should be (and it seems to be that really is) compatible with Win10 - take a look at [one thread](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33848/will-blender-be-compatible-with-windows-10), [second](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34901/does-blender-work-in-windows-10) - then you are facing some OS problems as it seems to work for other people.

Comment: Okay version v2.72b works for me fine.