# Will my Blender installation work after updating to windows 10?

Tags: windows

I'm thinking of installing win 10 and was wondering if I will be able to pick up everything where I left it...
Obviously I cannot request a 100% guaranteed result but I want to know if anyone has updated to win 10 and then run blender without a problem. Or did you have troubles? Anecdotal evidence welcome, it is surprisingly hard to come by :)

---

Thank you guys. I went with the update and (for what it's worth) everything went well. I barely notice that I changed OS, my files and apps are all there.
Of course this is my own experience. Backup your data to be on the safe side.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33848/is-blender-compatible-with-windows-10 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34901/does-blender-work-in-windows-10. There are [cases](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34798/blender-not-working-in-windows-10-any-suggestions) when it's not working, still they should be solvable.

Comment: The only issue I had when upgrading to windows 10 was that the drivers for my GPU didn't update automatically to a compatible version. Once I updated them I had Zero issues.

Comment: Please accept an answer to let others to know that it is ok more than explaining it in the question. You could answer your own questions if you have an answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 've gone from windows 7 to 10 and haven't had any problems. For safety of course save all your projects in an external hard drive, but you better wait other answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can save your files in a save place, uninstall blender, update to windows 10, and install the last version of blender (2.77a when writing this) so you have a clean version.

As you can see in blender.org the last version is "Compatible with Windows 10 | 8 | 7 | Vista" so you won't have any* problem.

*Or at least not more problems than with windows 7.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. Blender 2.79 didn't want to start on Windows 10.
I used Intel® Driver & Support Assistant https://www.intel.ru/content/www/ru/ru/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html
which updated couple Intel drivers on my laptop including Graphics Driver.
After restarting the system, the problem was solved - Blender starts and works well.

So yeah, it's the graphics driver problem as mentioned before.