# Blender doesn't open after Windows 10 creators update

Tags: windows

As the title says, ever since I updated to the latest version of Windows 10, Blender won't open. I haven't done anything that could have broke it. After installing the update I tried opening it on Steam, it just opened the console type window which gets closed and then nothing happens.

I tried to re-install the Steam version - Result = Same problem
Tried installing non-steam version - Result = Same problem.

Anyone else has this issue?

I really want to carry on with my project but can't carry on :/

Comment: "I haven't done anything that could have broke it" looks like you have which was Windows 10. Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34798/blender-not-working-in-windows-10-any-suggestions, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33848/is-blender-compatible-with-windows-10

Comment: Also make sure you clear your user preferences between installs (more important than reinstalling), and update your graphics card drivers to the lates stable release available.

Comment: right click on Blender and try to run it under integrated graphics and see if it starts .

Comment: I had the same problem. Running with integrated graphics allowed it to run. I'll try updating my graphics drivers. ...stupid Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. I updated my drivers and went into the blender folder that's under the program files folder and just clicked on that application. Now it works again.

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Updating my drivers did not solve my case...

As derHugo notified at [Blender doesn't open after Windows 10 creators update](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79684/blender-doesnt-open-after-windows-10-creators-update/79721)

Disabling **'high constrast'** setting made the trick for me

> setting-> personalisation->Colours-> Choose your default App mode ->
>   Light

Also, it seemed that i had to disable a personalized theme to take a Windows provided theme, for ex:**'themed background'**

> setting-> personalisation->Themes

Hope it will do the trick for you